# Can't set the Wireless configuration to "ad-hoc" in Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi-driver, ad-hoc-network

Ubuntu doesn't allow me to connect to any ad-hoc networks. Doing a little research I find that it is my wireless settings so I executed the command that switches from Infrastructure mode to ad-hoc but it never lets me do it. Here's what I tried and the results from the terminal:

```
example@EXAMPLE-UBUNTU:~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

I've already made sure that it is wlan0 what corresponds to my wireless connection. I don't seem to be able to connect to *any* ad-hoc network whatsoever. My device is the popular "Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n" as I learnt after executing

```
lspci
```

in a bash terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your device/driver doesn't support ad-hoc mode.

Try using a different driver, it seemed to work for this guy:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155752